# How to avoid writing the same R clause 6 times

Tags: r

I'm including a revised edit based on the suggested solution below:

```
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library('scales')


Macro <- read.csv("P:/R/Macro.csv")

foo <- function (start) {

  mycontrol <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",
                            initialWindow = 8,
                            horizon = 1,
                            fixedWindow = FALSE, 
                            savePredictions = TRUE)


  myfit <- train(Y ~ X1372C + S1 + S2 + S3,
                 data = Macro[start:14, ,drop = FALSE],
                 method = "lm",
                 trControl = mycontrol)

  c(myfit$pred)  ## return; drop dimension as a vector
}


Forecast <- sapply(1:6, foo)  ## will simplify to matrix

dput(Forecast)
```

This translates into this
output:

Warning messages:
1: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
2: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
3: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
4: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
5: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
6: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.

> dput(Forecast)
>   structure(list(c(921.172565647808, 926.099130620101, 1240.09797589312, 
>   942.482635914736, 955.942081354932, 977.408884588125), c(977.0702941, 
>   943.8941538, 1272.797631, 981.859451, 995.574098, 1052.287953
>   ), 9:14, c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), c("Training1", 
>   "Training2", "Training3", "Training4", "Training5", "Training6"
>   ), c(926.678510620924, 1241.54853541131, 943.689699182586, 952.297326382802, 
>   979.924409311149), c(943.8941538, 1272.797631, 981.859451, 995.574098, 
>   1052.287953), 9:13, c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), c("Training1", 
>   "Training2", "Training3", "Training4", "Training5"), c(1257.33305898499, 
>   951.366992832791, 957.163715037822, 986.364307731912), c(1272.797631, 
>   981.859451, 995.574098, 1052.287953), 9:12, c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
>   TRUE), c("Training1", "Training2", "Training3", "Training4"), 
>       c(993.427314382052, 978.520174690649, 1067.16914028792), 
>       c(981.859451, 995.574098, 1052.287953), 9:11, c(TRUE, TRUE, 
>       TRUE), c("Training1", "Training2", "Training3"), c(987.694506364155, 
>       1102.00413769988), c(995.574098, 1052.287953), 9:10, c(TRUE, 
>       TRUE), c("Training1", "Training2"), 1058.30501548728, 1052.287953, 
>       9L, TRUE, "Training1"), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(c("pred", 
>   "obs", "rowIndex", "intercept", "Resample"), NULL))

dput(Macro[1:14, ])
structure(list(Qtrs = structure(1:14, .Label = c("14_Q2", "14_Q3", 
"14_Q4", "15_Q1", "15_Q2", "15_Q3", "15_Q4", "16_Q1", "16_Q2", 
"16_Q3", "16_Q4", "17_Q1", "17_Q2", "17_Q3"), class = "factor"), 
    Y = c(865.8283846, 856.0688462, 1165.958691, 883.3432512, 
    902.1949231, 897.0950769, 1237.512923, 962.5309231, 977.0702941, 
    943.8941538, 1272.797631, 981.859451, 995.574098, 1052.287953
    ), X1372C = c(0.906148417, 0.882519787, 1.329575232, 1.088817819, 
    1.180987191, 1.167632493, 1.593644333, 1.178410516, 1.226391569, 
    1.221516083, 1.605735851, 1.202507143, 1.243837663, 1.339676971
    ), X5244C = c(0.906148417, 0.882519787, 1.329575232, 1.088817819, 
    1.180987191, 1.167632493, 1.593644333, 1.178410516, 1.226391569, 
    1.221516083, 1.605735851, 1.202507143, 1.243837663, 1.339676971
    ), X5640C = c(0.668605303, 0.650010329, 0.871325692, 0.657860513, 
    0.717979329, 0.734934807, 0.987398267, 0.729793323, 0.811565803, 
    0.820667752, 1.072773575, 0.783936578, 0.864640587, 0.954630807
    ), X6164C = c(0.405020101, 0.372197584, 0.518686161, 0.373651444, 
    0.407590328, 0.406092873, 0.560442245, 0.417412494, 0.429938649, 
    0.461566266, 0.592980109, 0.444907445, 0.47447048, 0.558013448
    ), X1372B = c(1.874539814, 1.816307314, 2.538860638, 1.785564496, 
    1.877335003, 1.896950271, 2.677640702, 2.057301773, 2.060862256, 
    2.010340805, 2.749691737, 2.112415534, 2.123956718, 2.264930431
    ), X5244B = c(1.874539814, 1.816307314, 2.538860638, 1.785564496, 
    1.877335003, 1.896950271, 2.677640702, 2.057301773, 2.060862256, 
    2.010340805, 2.749691737, 2.112415534, 2.123956718, 2.264930431
    ), X5640B = c(2.784147985, 2.728887944, 3.915195977, 3.036215525, 
    3.037519069, 3.035750269, 4.235355932, 3.304887671, 3.26268204, 
    3.141199768, 4.294197969, 3.274759241, 3.281116188, 3.501393693
    ), X6164B = c(0.791458844, 0.78168066, 1.18611112, 0.859852789, 
    0.944191582, 0.976372468, 1.397898629, 1.099556909, 1.128398283, 
    1.131976904, 1.580815657, 1.206596743, 1.245306897, 1.358211802
    ), X1372V = c(0.097143401, 0.097524773, 0.141261151, 0.115168338, 
    0.120877067, 0.119050862, 0.157452868, 0.117294253, 0.11874258, 
    0.117416967, 0.154157986, 0.117553225, 0.117734259, 0.126540804
    ), X5244V = c(0.097143401, 0.097524773, 0.141261151, 0.115168338, 
    0.120877067, 0.119050862, 0.157452868, 0.117294253, 0.11874258, 
    0.117416967, 0.154157986, 0.117553225, 0.117734259, 0.126540804
    ), X5640V = c(0.064650539, 0.063541823, 0.083794768, 0.063561861, 
    0.06730385, 0.068859437, 0.089436159, 0.066723151, 0.072244789, 
    0.072641489, 0.095058099, 0.070520087, 0.075122879, 0.082610429
    ), X6164V = c(0.044563645, 0.042226354, 0.057467132, 0.042275768, 
    0.043796282, 0.043972939, 0.059422138, 0.044436698, 0.044714835, 
    0.047485033, 0.060888955, 0.046498904, 0.047787208, 0.055743044
    ), X1372BV = c(0.211443705, 0.20868086, 0.281834069, 0.198443943, 
    0.205496416, 0.207598984, 0.285816341, 0.21745711, 0.21640918, 
    0.210584615, 0.283752378, 0.218344658, 0.215849274, 0.229469246
    ), X5244BV = c(0.211443705, 0.20868086, 0.281834069, 0.198443943, 
    0.205496416, 0.207598984, 0.285816341, 0.21745711, 0.21640918, 
    0.210584615, 0.283752378, 0.218344658, 0.215849274, 0.229469246
    ), X5640BV = c(0.27897666, 0.2771921, 0.387651075, 0.297277243, 
    0.293774368, 0.293731964, 0.400189046, 0.309076866, 0.302470138, 
    0.29076674, 0.39564161, 0.301178985, 0.297513626, 0.315261748
    ), X6164BV = c(0.087276144, 0.089506522, 0.130605096, 0.094950656, 
    0.101815228, 0.105435663, 0.148800072, 0.115872327, 0.118331193, 
    0.118122767, 0.163058, 0.124425055, 0.126056291, 0.136434954
    ), S1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L), S2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L), S3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Qtrs", "Y", "X1372C", "X5244C", 
"X5640C", "X6164C", "X1372B", "X5244B", "X5640B", "X6164B", "X1372V", 
"X5244V", "X5640V", "X6164V", "X1372BV", "X5244BV", "X5640BV", 
"X6164BV", "S1", "S2", "S3"), row.names = c(NA, 14L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: So many ways...

Comment: Please take a shot - what is the most concise/efficient way?  Thank you!

Comment: the only think varying is the starting index of subset, so just have a i mentioned there..thats it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your clauses only differ in the `data` used. More precisely, the subset of your dataset `Macro`. Even more precisely, the starting row of the subset. So why not write a function?

```
foo <- function (start) {

  mycontrol <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",
                            initialWindow = 8,
                            horizon = 1,
                            fixedWindow = FALSE, 
                            savePredictions = TRUE)


  myfit <- train(Y ~ X1372C + S1 + S2 + S3,
                 data = Macro[start:14, ,drop = FALSE],
                 method = "lm",
                 trControl = mycontrol)

  c(myfit$pred)  ## return; drop dimension as a vector
  }
```

Then

```
Forecast <- sapply(1:6, foo)  ## will simplify to matrix
```

Finally, your `F9` to `F14` are just row sums of lower triangular (plus diagonal) of matrix `Forecast`:

```
upper.tri(Forecast) <- 0
rowSums(Forecast)
```

Comment: I got the following error when implementing the last 2 lines:  > upper.tri(Forecast) <- 0
Error in upper.tri(Forecast) <- 0 : could not find function "upper.tri<-"
> rowSums(Forecast)
Error in rowSums(Forecast) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: That spits out quite a bit of output - what is this supposed to show?  dput(Forecast)
structure(list(c(921.172565647808, 926.099130620101, 1240.09797589312, 
942.482635914736, 955.942081354932, 977.408884588125), c(977.0702941, 
943.8941538, 1272.797631, 981.859451, 995.574098, 1052.287953
), 9:14, c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), c("Training1", 
"Training2", "Training3", "Training4", "Training5", "Training6"
), c(926.678510620924, 1241.54853541131, 943.689699182586, 952.297326382802,

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code quickly, but this should work. I suggest you have a look at [defining functions in R](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/intro_function.htm).

```
clauseLoop <- function(startPoint) {
    myControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",
                      initialWindow = 8,
                      horizon = 1,
                      fixedWindow = FALSE, 
                      savePredictions = TRUE)

    myFit <- train(Y ~ X1372C + S1 + S2 + S3,
                   data = startPoint,
                   method = "lm",
                   trControl = mycontrol)

    Forecast <- myFit$pred
}

ForecastX <- clauseLoop("x <- Macro[6:14,]")
```